# Using "<<" or "+" to put strings together when using "cout"

Tags: c++, console, cout

I have seen people output different strings together by using both "<<" and "+".

```
cout << firstname << lastname << endl;
```

versus:

```
cout << firstname + lastname << endl;
```

Is it better to use "<<" or does it not make much of a difference?

Comment: You could also do a test which is faster and post the results.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring `std::string` for `operator+` concatenation? This won't work with raw `const char *`s.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Definitely, use `<<` - concatenating the string will create a copy of the two strings pasted together. Whether it also allocates extra memory on top is a matter of how strings are implemented in the C++ library, but if the first and last names are "long enough" (bigger than 8-16 characters together), then it most likely WILL allocate memory (and then free it again when the temporary copy is no longer needed).

The `<<` operator will have very little overhead in comparison, so no doubt it is better.

Of course, unless you do thousands of these things, it's unlikely that you will have a measurable difference. But it's good to not waste CPU cycles, you never know what good use they can be somewhere else... ;)

Comment: See also: [premature pessimization](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mmjVIC6WolgC&pg=PT90)

Answer (score 20):

I would say its better to use `<<` in that particular case. Otherwise, concatenation results in a temporary which *could* allocate memory for no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Cascading `<<` is a better choice.

For performance, as the other theads mentioned, operator `<<` doesn't necessarily introduce any temporary object. A cascading `<<` can be considered as a pipe.

Also sometimes, you cannot use `+` if your left-hand operand is not a user-defined type, unless you provide the corresponding `operator+`. E.g.,

```
cout << "Hello, " << lastname << endl;// Works
cout << "Hello, " + lastname << endl; // This won't work
```

Comment: For the last line to not work, it would require a really poor implementation of a string type. It will certainly work with `std::string`.

Comment: Yes, std::string does have that support.

Comment: @K-ballo: Exactly as written, the last line is a const char[], and thus it doesn't support the + operator
    cout << std::string("Hello, ") + lastname << endl; would work